# After alias, script didn't get variable

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to `alias mytest='/usr/bin/python3.6'`.

And, it can work when I type mytest in terminal, I can use python3.6 manually.

However, when I tried to run in script, it would go out some import errors.

My script like this: `mytest test.py $1 $2`
Run on bash test.sh /home/data1 /home/data2
[Command like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQ48i.jpg)

Comment: Can you post the actual alias line you are having issue with?

Comment: BTW, not directly related to your problem, but `mytest test.py $1 $2` is generally buggy -- if your `$1` and `$2` values contain spaces they can be split into multiple arguments; if they contain no characters not present in `IFS` they can simply be ignored outright; etc. Much better to use `"$1" "$2"` if you really want to pass exactly those two strings, or `"$@"` if you want to pass through the whole argument list.

Comment: Bigger issue, though -- aliases aren't supported in scripts by default at all. They're an interactive facility -- POSIX-compliant shells without extensions for interactive use aren't even required to support them.

Comment: If you used an exported function -- `mytest() { /usr/bin/python3.6 "$@"; }; export -f mytest` -- *that* would be supported in scripts with a bash shebang (`/bin/sh` is not guaranteed to honor exported functions, as they're a bash extension), though it's better practice to use an actual script called `mytest` at a location in the PATH.

Comment: I added my situation about my server. Thanks a lot

Comment: Please post content as text, not graphical screenshots, wherever possible to do so. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122

Comment: @Achaca, also, running `sh yourscript` means it's running with `sh`, not `bash`, even if the shebang at the top of the script is `#!/bin/bash`. As I said above, you need to use `bash` for exported functions to be honored (and, well, you need to actually define an exported function, not an alias).

Comment: okay got it, thanks a lot